# Copyright issues in games

Tags: android

I have developed an android game which is a puzzle type game. 
since I am a fan of iron man myself and want to use its wallpapers in my gaming area background 
so my question is can I use it in my game without violations of copyright issues because I have seen some apps on playstore which uses iron man content like this 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.celfishmedia.ironman3

thanks in advance

Comment: Don't assume they're not paying for the right to use that material. Your question is one for a lawyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no. That isn't how copyright works. If you use someone else's copyrighted material without an agreement with the copyright holder, you are in violation of their copyright and they can tell you to remove the infringing parts of your work.

Long answer, ask a lawyer, because I'm not one. But in general, here's how it is:

Some companies are very laid back about fan-made content/use of copyrighted material and won't enforce their copyright unless you're doing something really bad that they'd rather not have their work associated with, or if you're profiting from it. Others will send out cease-and-desist letters for just about everything that would be considered infringing.

If you do choose to include those wallpapers, the worst that will happen at first is that you'll receive a cease-and-desist letter kindly asking you to remove the wallpapers or face legal action. If for some very stupid reason you choose to keep them, you will be faced with a lawsuit, and you will lose. Hands down. This question alone is enough evidence to show that you knew you were infringing on some copyrights.

---

As for the example, if you look at the other apps Cellfish has released, you'll see they have a bunch of company logos front and center, and all their apps describe themselves as the "official" app of that kind for that company/IP.

With those kinds of download numbers, they'd have the pants sued off of them by now were they not properly licensing the copyrighted material.

Some quick Googling revealed that Cellfish does way more than just make a few apps and that they were probably hired to make those apps by the copyright holders.

> Marvel is pleased to continue extending its digital offerings, now to Android wallpapers, with our new partners at Cellfish.  It adds a lot of value for Avengers fans worldwide." said Peter Phillips, Senior Vice President and General Manager of Marvel Digital Media Group.

From [this press release](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=38433).